# C# excel addin - Accessing Controls

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

I am working on an addin for excel 2010 using C#.  I have an existing worksheet that has some controls in it, namely a ComboBox.  I am trying to write some code that will place a certain value in the combo box's text property, but I am having a hard time getting access to the control to do so.

The combo box is named 'ComboBox1' but if I try something like...

```
var combo = Controls["ComboBox1"];
```

I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Exploratory approaches to finding out what I am supposed to be doing aren't really providing useful information either.  For example, if were to write;

```
MessageBox.Show(Controls[0].GetType())
```

The displayed message is 'NamedRangeImpl' which doesn't seem like a control at all.  So my question is, how do I get access to the controls that are on my worksheet from my code?

Comment: Did you add it as a form control or an ActiveX control?  If it's an ActiveX control try `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").object.value = "foo"`

Comment: Good question.  I didn't make the sheet, but I will find out what is what.

Comment: You could try loop something like `foreach (Control c in Controls) MessageBox.Show(c.GetType().ToString());` and see what the output of that is.

Comment: @Mark, the type is mentioned in the question. They all come back as 'NamedRangeImpl'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure about the problem but I've made addins for word and if its like windows forms this should work nicely.

```
foreach (Control c in Controls) 
   if (c.Name == "comboBox1") {
      ComboBox box = (ComboBox)c;
      box.Items.Add("Thing added");
   }
```